# What is the difference between ViewEncapsulation.None and :host, :host /deep/?

Tags: angular, angular2viewencapsulation

I have an Angular 6 custom form control which I have created as a wrapper around another control so that we can apply our own css rules.

I have removed the `ViewEncapsulation` on this wrapper component so that we can hook on to the css classes generated by the existing form control and overwrite the rules.

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

A reviewer suggested me to use the combination of `:host` and `:host::ng-deep` rather than using `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

I don't know why that could be better. Can someone explain?

Comment: check this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: @Chellappan I will have all the styles under `::ng-deep`. Which ultimately will not be scoped or encapsulated (same as ViewEncapsulation.None). So why would one be preferred over the other?

Comment: ::ng-deep us special selectors that has been taken from shadow DOM style scoping  and it is not wildly support by all browser.